# Proxy file on snakemake code

Tags: snakemake

I want to do alignment using star and I use proxy file for star the alignment. 
Without a proxy file star-align  run also without  reference. So if I gave as input  constrain of the alignment process the presence of database.done the alignment process can start.
How can manage this situation?

```
rule star_index:
    input:
        config['references']['transcriptome_fasta']
    output:
          genome=config['references']['starindex_dir'],
          tp=touch("database.done")
    shell:
          'STAR --limitGenomeGenerateRAM 54760833024 --runMode genomeGenerate --genomeDir {output.genome} --genomeFastaFiles {input}'




rule star_map:
    input:
        dt="trim/{sample}/",
        forward_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_paired.fq.gz",
        reverse_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_paired.fq.gz",
        forward_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_unpaired.fq.gz",
        reverse_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz",
        t1p="database.done",
    output:
        out1="ALIGN/{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam",
        out2="ALIGN/{sample}/",
       # out2=touch("Star.align.done")
    params:
        genomedir = config['references']['basepath'],
        sample="mitico",
        platform_unit=config['platform'],
        cente=config['center']
    threads: 12
    log: "ALIGN/log/{params.sample}_star.log"
    shell:
        'mkdir -p ALIGN/;STAR --runMode alignReads  --genomeDir {params.genomedir} '
        r' --outSAMattrRGline  ID:{params.sample} SM:{params.sample} PL:{config[platform]}  PU:{params.platform_unit} CN:{params.cente} '
        '--readFilesIn   {input.forward_paired} {input.reverse_paired}  \
       --readFilesCommand zcat 
       --outWigType wiggle \
       --outWigStrand Stranded --runThreadN  {threads} --outFileNamePrefix  {output.out2}  2> {log} '
```

How can start a module only after all the previous function have finished.
I mean.Here i create the index then I trim ll my data and then I staart the alignment. I want after finishis all this sstep for all the sample start a new  function like run fastqc. How can decode this in snakemake?
thanks so much for patience help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any mention of the genome as a required input for "star_map", I believe the rule is starting too early.

Try moving the genome reference from being a "Parameter" to being an "Input" requirement for star_map. Snakemake doesn't wait for parameters, only inputs. All reference genomes should be listed as inputs. In fact, **all required files should be listed as input requirements**. Param's are just for mostly convenience; ad-hoc strings and things on the fly.

I'm not entirely sure as to the connectivity across your files, some of these references are to a YAML file you have not provided, so I cannot guarantee the code will work.

```
rule star_map:
    input:
        dt="trim/{sample}/",
        forward_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_paired.fq.gz",
        reverse_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_paired.fq.gz",
        forward_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_unpaired.fq.gz",
        reverse_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz",
        # Including the gnome as a required input, so Snakemake knows to wait for it too.
        genomedir = config['references']['basepath'],
    output:
        out1="ALIGN/{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam",
        out2="ALIGN/{sample}/",
```

Snakemake doesn't check what files your shell commands are touching and modifying. Snakemake only knows to coordinate the files described in the "input" and "output" directives.

Comment: thanks so much!! for  the last sentence.. How can encode on snakemake code the time when start rules. I wrote above the fact  I want to run fastqc only after all  the other steps are  run (after trimming, indexinng alignment).

Comment: You will not specify the "time", but rather, the "dependency". Make sure the output of star_map (the bam file) is included as an input requirement in the fastqc file. [See my Snakemake fastq file here](https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/blob/master/modules/fastqUtil/fastqc). My directive pathing in fastqc uses multiple wildcards, this is a bit more tricky and I maybe don't recommend you implement this level of generality, at least not yet.